# Why PHP get empty array from checkbox with the dynamic values?

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I have a table:

[image]

This table returns records from BD. A user can add any person from an entry to the group he created.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
         <table class="table table-dark table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr >
            <div class="row">
                <th >Add</th>
                <th >id</th>
                <th >first_name</th>
                <th >last_name</th>
                <th >Groups</th>
            </div>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($my_subordinates as $my_subordinate):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><input type="checkbox" name="grouped[]" value="<?php $my_subordinate['id']?>">to group</td>
                        <td ><?php echo $my_subordinate['id'] ?></td>
                        <td ><?php echo $my_subordinate['first_name'] ?></td>
                        <td ><?php echo $my_subordinate['last_name'] ?></td>
                        <td ><?php  ?></td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
            <div class="form-group row">
               <label for="name" class="col-4 col-form-label">Group name</label> 
               <div class="col-4">
                  <input id="group_name" name="group_name" pattern="{2,255}" value="" class="form-control here" type="text" autofocus required>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="offset-4 col-8">
                    <button name="create_group" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
         </form>
```

The value in checkbox gets users id and when user selects some persons, ids must be passed to `$ _POST`. 
Here:

```
if(isset($_POST['create_group']))
{
   b_dump($_POST);
}
```

I check `$ _POST`, when the button 'create_group'is pressed.
But the array is empty:

here I chose all three employees

[image]

Why is it like this? 
*If you know simpler ways to add people to groups, I would be interested to know)*

Comment: could you add the whole form?

Comment: @RamRaider, one moment

Comment: @VladislavFinder You have missed to `echo` the value in checkbox.

Comment: You have some invalid markup in that html table - `<div class="row">` cannot be at that location. Better would be `<tr class='row'>` if anything. That does not explain the empty array however - but there is a spurious `<td ><?php  ?></td>` ~ an empty cell. That said, `<?php $my_subordinate['id']?>` should be `<?php echo $my_subordinate['id']?>`

Comment: @DeepakSingh, it helped me, thanks!

Comment: @RamRaider, thank you too

Comment: glad you have resolved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to echo it.

Do it like this:

```
<td ><input type="checkbox" name="grouped[]" value="<?php echo $my_subordinate['id']?>">to group</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to echo the value.

```
value="<?php $my_subordinate['id']?>">
```

has to be

```
value="<?php  echo $my_subordinate['id']?>">
```

or

```
value="<?=  $my_subordinate['id']?>">
```